# Zend view script path setup

Tags: zend-framework, templates, zend-view

Here is the code I have:

```
$this->getView()->setScriptPath($templatePath);
$this->_helper->viewRenderer($page);
```

This code is handled in the Core_PageController view action. The problem I have is now the view object looks for my script files in `$templatePath/page` since page is the controller. What I'd like is for the view object to look in just the `$templatePath` directory path (without the page directory);

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instruct the `ViewRenderer` to not use the controller name as part of the view script path.

To do that, try:

```
$this->_helper
     ->viewRenderer
     ->setNoController(true); // do not use controller name as part of the view path
```

> **setNoController($flag = true)** can be used to tell **render()** not to look
>   for the action script in a subdirectory named after the controller
>   (which is the default behaviour). **getNoController()** retrieves the
>   current value.

More info on the [ViewRenderer helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer).